# Has the idea of splitting the philosophy stackexchange ever been discussed?

Tags: discussion

This stackexchange has been stormed by non-philosopher (in the academical sense). To some extent, this can be a great source of naïve and yet profound questions.

However, as it is way easier to write your opinion than a real educated and sourced answer, this as devolved into a pub-like forum. Anything that entertains the passer-by is upvoted (see [this recent question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/111180/pattern-of-shoppers-arriving-to-a-cash-register)) and an army of well-established and enthusiastic opinion givers encourages vague and out of place questions (see [for example those answers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72800/what-are-the-most-rational-basic-beliefs)). This has been going for [a very long time](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/professional-philosophers-on-philosophy-se/3112#comment4016_3116) and likely won't change—those people not reflecting on their own practice of philosophy and invasion of the quasi-public space.

Now this is a natural phenomenon. Any beginner in a field has different standards of rigour and exactitude. When those form the great majority of a community, the standards of said community are logically lowered. This may be a good thing to help beginners express themselves in such a field, still imprecisely but without feeling that they are shutdown.

But then, this become a place for beginners and not a place for academical (or research-level) discussions. This is fine because one natural work-around is simply to have two distinct SEs. This is the solution which has been put in place for mathematics: there are math.SE for any kind of beginner or student question and mathoverflow for academical questions.

Has such a separation been envisaged or discussed for philosophy? What does the moderation team think?

One obvious counter-argument would be that there would be too few participants in the academical philosophy SE, as clearly we see very few questions or answers which respect the actual standard to which this SE tried to live up. But I think that all the people actually capable of doing philosophy and who left this SE over the years because of its pub-like state would already make a big enough community.

Answer (score 6):

I understand, and substantially agree, with what you are saying. Too many answers here are nothing more than statements of personal opinion rather than an attempt to give an account of a subject or question. The splitting that you describe happens on the mathematics part of StackExchange. There is a Mathematics SE for general math Q&A and also MathOverflow for professional mathematicians. I doubt whether this would work for philosophy.

1. The volume of posts and answers here is much lower than it is on the math sites. I suspect there would be very few posts on a Philosophy Overflow site.
2. It would be extra work for moderators. Somebody would have to decide which questions merit being on the Overflow site and which answers do not meet the standards for being an authoritative answer.
3. In my experience, professional philosophers are reticent to participate in public forums. Maybe my experience is not typical, but a lot of philosophers will draft papers, present them to other philosophers in order to get feedback and then go straight to publication. Discussing philosophy on a public forum provides no academic kudos and discussions quickly degenerate in quality because everyone and his dog thinks they are qualified to contribute.
4. The question and answer format is not ideal for philosophical discussion.

Comment: Your first point is surely the most problematic--and I agree that it is not clear at all whether there would be enough activity. 3. is somewhat related to this first point. However, I think that for 2. and 4. it would actually be the opposite. Q&A format is way better suited for questions regarding, say, a specific excerpt or a specific concept from a philosophical work, than for questions which more or less amount to "what is the meaning of life?"

Comment: And further, stricter standards often mean easier moderation. E.g. if we require that answers support their claim by citing relevant philosophical work, it is very quick to see which does and which doesn't and the answer which do will very often be of a good overall quality. It is similar to the time spent grading a good student versus a less good student. That said, I agree that the overall work for moderation would be at least greater.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I do not think this would work out for the reasons @Bumble gave. I would, maybe, add that professional philosophers still tend to be bookworms rather than tech cracks (ie. have problems setting up a moodle course on their own and generally shy away from anything that has to do with IT).

There have been several tries over the years to make this site more attractive for serious philosophy and academics but the format basically depends either on people

- having specific, narrow questions they cannot answer themselves (almost exclusively students and academics that usually get their answers out of relevant literature or discussions with other academics on international congresses, talks, and lectures), or
- very literate or motivated, with the according resources like access to databases and books, **time**, and the will to research and answer the questions on the appropriate level (almost exclusively **former academics** since the rest usually lacks the time or skills)

The only alternative I see is to get a lot of professionals onto the site in  a one-off movement to get the thing going. Before that makes sense, we would need a joint effort to get a hand on all the junk (sorry if that sounds elitist) that predominantly makes up the site at this moment. Three pro bono moderators just cannot handle this on their own. We would need to work full shifts 24/7 for months to do that. And many (almost all) high-rep users that have the rep and experience to do so do not really engage in moderation duties and meta discussions.

Maybe another alternative would be a StackExchange Team site running for philosophy professionals only. Here, the question of financing remains the main problem besides getting the people there in the first place